# Amortized time of dynamic array

Tags: algorithm, amortized-analysis

As a simple example, in a specific implementation of the dynamic array, we double the size of the array each time it fills up. 
Because of this, array reallocation may be required, and in the worst case an insertion may require O(n). 
However, a sequence of n insertions can always be done in O(n) time, because the rest of the insertions are done in constant time, so n insertions can be completed in O(n) time. 
The amortized time per operation is therefore O(n) / n = O(1).
--from Wiki

But in another book :Each doubling takes O(n) time, but happens so rarely that its amortized time is still O(1).

Hope somebody could tell me does the rare situation infer the Wiki explanation? Thanks

Comment: The "other book" doesn't say anything, it's a vague and imprecise way of describing what the wiki said. This is your homework, no? Follow the analysis yourself and figure it out ;)

Answer (score 24):

Amortized basically means average per number of operations.

So, if you have an array of n, you need to insert **n+1 items** until you'll need the reallocation.

So, you've done **n inserts** which each one of them took **O(1)**, and another insert that took **O(n)**, so in total you've got **n+1 actions** that cost you **2n operations** .

```
2n / n+1  ~= 1
```

That's why the Amortized time is still **O(1)**

Comment: Shouldn't the cost be 2n+1 here?

Comment: @GauravSharma No. Becuase when n+1 element is added, the array is doubled, which means 'n' items are copied + 1 element is append. So n+1 operations are made, which translates to O(n). So append takes O(n) time. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @SuryaTejaVemparala append only takes O(n) every 1/n appends, so on average it is inconsequential. `2n / n+1` does not `~= 1`, it `~= 2` - but constants are generally dropped for O() analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these two statements say the same thing, Wiki just explains it more thoroughly.